# can't open PLY file with blender

Tags: blender, ply-file-format

I've created a PLY file and I'm trying to open it with blender.
Unfortunately it doesn't work and I can't understand why or how exactly that PLY stuff work.

[Here is my code](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:46ac).

and

Error message:
[image: Error message]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you are making the ply file by hand or your own exporter.

The second last line in your screenshot is the clue to the answer - `Invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'30.5'` 30.5 happens to be the second number on your first data line.

In your file you have

```
property int32 x
property int32 y
property int32 z
property uchar red
property uchar green
property uchar blue
```

This would specify what data is on each line. `int32` is a 32 bit integer which will only hold whole numbers, but you have several ending with `.5`

If you want integers only then ensure the data matches that specification. If you want to use floating point numbers then specify `float` for the x,y,z data elements.